# RSelenium behind corporate proxy/firewall

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver

I am trying running Selenium to scrape information from my company's internal websites. I kept running into the following error:

> driver<- rsDriver(browser=c("chrome")
>
> checking Selenium Server versions: BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD Error in
> open.connection(con, "rb") :    Failed to connect to
> [www.googleapis.com](http://www.googleapis.com) port 443: Timed out

I have tried solutions from this post but it doesnt work
[RSelenium behind proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50388282/rselenium-behind-proxy)

I also searched on the forum as there are tons of people having similar problems in the past but not many of them is R related. Other posts involved functions that now had been defunct. Is there any other way around it?