# Timeout was reached: [www.googleapis.com] Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds (RSelenium)

Tags: r, rselenium

I am facing exactly the same issue, which can be found here: ([rsDriver error when executed through company's network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60667366/rsdriver-error-when-executed-through-companys-network)), while running the rsDriver() function to open up the internet explorer via my business laptop.

It seems question was answered by the person who asked the question. However, I think, it needs a little bit clarification. Since I am a newbie here I cannot comment his/her answer.

CODE:

```
rD <- rsDriver(browser="internet explorer")
```

ERROR:

```
checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : 
  Timeout was reached: [www.googleapis.com] Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance